# How do I enable my base employee class to calculate age on the fly

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have created an employee base class

```py
class Employee():
    description = "A general employee"

    def __init__(self, employee_id: int, name: str, surname: str, dob: str):
        self.employee_id: int = employee_id
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.dob = parse(dob)
        self._age

    @property
    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        age = today.year - self.dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.dob.month, self.dob.day))
        return age
```

I ran the unit test on the `employee` class the test code below it fails.

```py
    def employee():
        return Employee(1001, 'John', 'Smith', '1975-08-25')
    ...
    class TestEmployee(TestCase):
        def test_age(self):
            age = employee.age('1975-08-25')
            assert age == 44
```

The results from test were:

```
>       age = employee.age('1975-08-25')
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'age'
```

Comment: How is `employee` defined?

Comment: ```def employee():
    return Employee(1001, 'John', 'Smith', '1975-08-25')```

Comment: in that case. you can just remove the dob (and the `()` from the call and directly `assert employee.age == 44`. owever, there is additional issues with this approach (see my answer below)

Comment: Adapted my sample test below to fit your definition of `employee()` - still with the strong hint that a hardcoded birth date will work for a maximum time of a year and then break.

Comment: great point re hard coded dob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@property` `age` should not get any parameters. You are giving the value that you later expect in `employee.dob` as a parameter right now.

The corrected test would be

```
def test_age(self):
    e = employee()
    age = e.age
    assert age == 44
```

However, this bears the issue that the age is calculated relative to `now()`, so this test will break at least once a year.

You can do one better by dynamically calculating the date of birth - this also enables you to test e.g. what the property would return a day before, after or exactly on the birthday:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def test_age(self):
    yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    employee = Employee(42, "Name" "Surname",'{year}-{month}-{day}'.format(year=yesterday.year - 44), month=yesterday.month, day=yesterday.day)
    age = employee.age
    assert age == 44
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot access year, month & day functions from string, you either need to pass date object or convert string date to date object.

emp_dob = datetime.datetime.strptime('1975-08-25', "%Y-%m-%d").date()

Then you can access emp_dob.year

Comment: Trusting, that the `parse()` method called in `__init__` is actually implemented, I rather expect the dob string passed to `age` to be the issue...

Comment: The `dob` string is converted to `datetime` in the constructor using `from dateutil.parser import parse`

Comment: Then I am very sure that my answer and my comment on your question are correct :-)